# dvipdfmx fails to find pdftex.map / kanjix.map in a fresh install-tl distro

Tags: texlive, installing, texmf, kpsewhich

**UPD:** I added full repro scripts at https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/cb638c61afc2fb4526d05e6c4c3b48b6

The warninngs of dvidpfmx:

```
warning: Couldn't open font map file "pdftex.map".
warning: Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map".
```

How do I get rid of these warnings? Is it a problem with the recent `install-tl` that places font maps into `texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/`, but does not mention `updmap` in `TEXFONTMAPS` definition in `texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`? Should I patch it manually?

The font maps are produced in `texlive/texmf-var`, but `texmf-var` is not found at all in `TEXFONTMAPS` definition. It seems that something is wrong with both `TEXMFVAR`/`TEXMFSYSVAR` setup and with `updmap` suffix.

I install TexLive as follows into `./texlive` and use a custom-built `kpsewhich` (I have no system-wide install), I do not do any manual calls of `updmap`:

```
URL_TEXLIVE_INSTALLER=http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz

wget --no-clobber $URL_TEXLIVE_INSTALLER
mkdir -p install-tl
tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz --strip-components=1 --directory=install-tl

echo selected_scheme scheme-basic > install-tl.profile
echo TEXDIR $PWD/texlive >> install-tl.profile
echo TEXMFLOCAL $PWD/texlive/texmf-local >> install-tl.profile
echo TEXMFSYSVAR $PWD/texlive/texmf-var >> install-tl.profile
echo TEXMFSYSCONFIG $PWD/texlive/texmf-config >> install-tl.profile
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_RESUME=1 $PWD/install-tl/install-tl -profile install-tl.profile
```

`pdftex.map` and `kanjix.map` are found in the TexLive tree, but the `texmf.cnf` does not contain `updmap` directory:

```
export TEXMFCNF=$PWD/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c
export TEXMFDIST=$PWD/texlive/texmf-dist
kpsewhich -debug 32 pdftex.map

# kdebug:start search(xname=texmf.cnf, must_exist=1, find_all=1, path=/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c).
# kdebug: path_search(file=texmf.cnf, must_exist=1, find_all=1, path=/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search(file=texmf.cnf, find_all=1, casefold=no)
# kdebug:start generic search(files=[ls-r ls-R], must_exist=1, find_all=1, path=/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var:/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search_list(files=[ls-r ls-R], find_all=1, casefold=no)
# kdebug:returning from generic search([ls-r ls-R]) => /mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-r /mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R
# kdebug:start search(xname=aliases, must_exist=1, find_all=1, path=/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var:/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist).
# kdebug: path_search(file=aliases, must_exist=1, find_all=1, path=/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config:/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var:/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search(file=aliases, find_all=1, casefold=no)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search(file=aliases, find_all=1, casefold=yes)
# kdebug:   casefold_readable_file(aliases) in /mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist => (nil)
# kdebug:returning from search(aliases) =>
# kdebug:kpse_find_file: searching for pdftex.map of type map (from texmf.cnf)
# kdebug:start generic search(files=[pdftex.map], must_exist=0, find_all=0, path=.:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-config/fonts/map/busytex//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/busytex//:/home/vadimkantorov/texmf/fonts/map/busytex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local/fonts/map/busytex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config/fonts/map/busytex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var/fonts/map/busytex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/busytex//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-config/fonts/map/pdftex//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex//:/home/vadimkantorov/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config/fonts/map/pdftex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-config/fonts/map/dvips//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips//:/home/vadimkantorov/texmf/fonts/map/dvips//:!!/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config/fonts/map/dvips//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips//:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips//:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-config/fonts/map///:/home/vadimkantorov/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map///:/home/vadimkantorov/texmf/fonts/map///:!!/mnt/c/Users/texmf-local/fonts/map///:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-config/fonts/map///:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/texmf-var/fonts/map///:!!/mnt/c/Users/user/busytex/bug/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map///)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search_list(files=[pdftex.map], find_all=0, casefold=no)
# kdebug:  dir_list_search_list(files=[pdftex.map], find_all=0, casefold=yes)
# kdebug:   casefold_readable_file(pdftex.map) in . => (nil)
# kdebug:returning from generic search([pdftex.map]) =>

find texlive -name pdftex.map
# texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map

find texlive -name kanjix.map
# texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map

find texlive -name texmf.cnf
# texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
# texlive/texmf.cnf

grep 'fonts/map' texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
# TEXFONTMAPS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/fonts/map/{$progname,pdftex,dvips,}//
```

Comment: The '//' characters at the end of the TEXFONTMAPS definition imply that subdirectories are also searched.

Comment: why are they not searched in reality? Is it some problem with environment variable exports? is it a problem with TEXMF variable? Thanks!

Comment: Adding `export TEXMFVAR=$PWD/texlive/texmf-var` was neceessary to make things work. Do you know why `TEXMFSYSVAR` in profile is not sufficient to point it to `./texlive/texmf-var` for proper font discovery?

Comment: In <TL root>/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf, TEXMFCNF is defined as a long list of directories. So manually defining TEXMF... variables might break things. In a standard upstream installation, kpsewhich is able to derive the location of the various trees automatically. And did you try to update the filename database, either from the command-line (mktexlsr) or from the GUI?

Comment: No I have not executed any commands besides `install-tl`. Full repro of what I did is at: https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/cb638c61afc2fb4526d05e6c4c3b48b6 (the error messages in `README.md` are no more, but the shell files are up-to-date).

Comment: One more thing: scheme-basic does not include support for the xetex engine, but scheme-small does. Do you also have problems with a normal interactive install and scheme-small?

Comment: I haven't tried them :( And for simple documents scheme-basic + xetex worked fine for me.